# EXPO useEffect not called on navigating to same screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, expo, onload

I have one screen which called useEffect when rendered first time in the flow.
The second time I navigate to the screen in the flow , use Effect is not called but I want to call a function upon first time before , after or during render function is called when we navigate a second time to the same screen.

Here is the navigate call for everytime navigating to this screen from various screens

```
navigation.navigate("x", { u:type, s:title});
```

The following is the structure for my screen. I am not using components but functions with navigation

```
const x = ({ navigation}) => {
    ...
   return (
    <View style={styles.a}>
            ...    
   </View>
  );
};

export default x;
```

Comment: if you are  using  React Navigation, try change useEffect to useFocusEffect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that a screen `remains mounted in react-native` after the initial navigation. Thus, a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array won't be called subsequently on navigation.

Notice that [this behavior differs from the web](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/).

> If you are coming to react-navigation from a web background, you may assume that when user navigates from route A to route B, A will unmount (its componentWillUnmount is called) and A will mount again when user comes back to it. While these React lifecycle methods are still valid and are used in react-navigation, their usage differs from the web.

The [recommended way to solve this is described here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/). For your case this can be solved as follows.

```js
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const x = ({ navigation}) => {
    
   useFocusEffect(
     React.useCallback(() => {
      // called when screen is focused, thus everytime on navigation
      return () => {
        // unfocus... cleanup ... or whatever
      };
    }, [])
  );

   ...

   return (
    <View style={styles.a}>
            ...    
   </View>
  );
};

export default x;
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` will be called on first load of your functional component or when some dependency will be changed. Everything remains the same, so your `useEffect` will not work. Consider using `useFocusEffect` from `react-navigation` lib instead.